# Why do we have to wait for a Video (over samba share) in VLC?

Tags: video-encoding, vlc

So.. We have a router that has an HDD on it and I share videos through samba.

Our problem is, when we want to watch videos like these:

```
file NOTX264AVI.avi
NOTX264AVI.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 720 x 304, 25.00 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
```

then we can scroll VLC to ex.: the half of the video and it plays it in the moment (that's great, because We don't have to wait for two minutes for the video..). But. When We watch videos like these:

```
file X264AVI.avi
X264AVI.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 576 x 320, 25.00 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
```

with VLC... we have to wait for a very long time until the video continues (if we scroll to ex.: to the half of the video).

**QUESTION**: So why does VLC downloads the X264AVI.avi until the part we want to watch, and why doesn't it downloads it when we want to watch NOTX264AVI.avi? Videos using X264 codecs can't be "streamed*"?

So I need to do something to VLC (?) so that it will "stream*" (?) the X264 videos too, but how?

*with streaming I mean that if we go to 1h10 minutes in a video (not using x264 video codec) then it will start immediately. But we have to wait minutes if we want to go to ex.: 1h10 minutes in a video that uses x264 codec.. (and I can see great network traffic when we are waiting for the video to ""load"")

Comment: why did I got a -1 ?

Comment: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/DivFix didn't helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/divfixpp/

was the solution..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a limitation of VLC, but probably a question of how the video is encoded, or served.   The issue is most likely one of two things:

1. The video meta data is not at the beginning of the file
2. The file is not being served using "chunked encoding"

In this particular case it seems that 1 is the more likely problem.  There are tools out there (it seems you found one already) that can analyze a video file and move the metadata to the beginning of the file.

qt-faststart is one utility to do this http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/